# Graphing First-Order ODE as Surface

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations, graphing-functions, 3d, coordinate-systems

Suppose I want to graph the general solution to a real first-order ODE as a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$.  What are the correct axes of the space in which this surface lives?

My first guess was that the horizontal axes represent the independent and dependent variables, and the vertical axis represents the constant of integration, but this has bizarre effect of "de-arbitrizing" that arbitrary constant.  For example, the general solutions $x^2 + y^2 = C$, $x^2 + y^2 = -C$ and $x^2 + y^2 + 500 = -e^{\pi + C}$ all have different graphs under this graphing methodology, even though they are the same general solution.

Comment: The third expression is not as general; $-500-e^{\pi+C}<-500$ for any real $C$. (And $-500-e^{\pi+C}\neq-500$ for any complex $C$.)

Comment: Why would you want to graph this in $\mathbb{R}^3$? It's more natural to view the solution set as a family of curves in $\mathbb{R}^2$ (the $xy$-plane), with $C$ being just a label for which curve is which. And labels are indeed arbitrary.

Comment: @HansLundmark It just seems to me that a surface in $\mathbb{R}^3$ would provide a more global view of the general solution, from which a particular solution could be obtained as a curve in $\mathbb{R}^2$ via vertically slicing.  The infinite family of curves view feels compressed, much like a contour plot, in that it's "really" an $\mathbb{R}^3$ graph flattened into $\mathbb{R}^2$ for graphing convenience at the expense of visual clarity (I think graphs like supply and demand fall into this category as well).